# How does a browser distinguish between a webpage and a media file

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, mozilla

I was simply wondering how does a browser distinguish between a webpage and a file, like if its a media file it prompts the user to specify the location where to save it.

Answer (score 1):

By inspecting the `Content-Type` header on the HTTP Response obtained by the browser from the webserver. 
IE:

```
Content-Type: text/html;
```

IE:

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg;
```

Comment: Side note: the option to download may be suppressed unless the `Content-Disposition` header is included (if it's a media type the browser can display natively, such as images, downloading is generally skipped).